# `when` reserved word in erlang

Tags: erlang

I started off this morning trying to work out what the 'when' statement is used for in erlang. I know the below example is wrong:

```
do_larger() ->
    io:format("Larger~n").

do_smaller() ->
    io:format("Smaller~n").


when_version(Size) ->
    when Size > 10 -> do_larger(),
    when Size < 10 -> do_smaller().
```

I decided to look at its implementation in Haskell to see if this would help and I ended up getting even more confused.

Is anyone able to point me at a tutorial (or explain to me) what the when statement is used for and how it's used in haskell and/ or erlang?

Comment: I don't know too much Haskell but when in Haskell and Erlang are quite different from what I see in the Haskell answers.

Comment: I'm removing the Haskell tag, as this really has nothing to do with Haskell.  You can write a function called "when" in pretty much any language.

Comment: Might want to consider renaming the question to "`when` reserved word in Erlang" or "`when` keyword in Erlang". Erlang doesn't have statements. #Pedantic

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `when` in Erlang is a guard on a clause.  This regards the pattern matching built into Erlang.  Your example must be:

```erlang
when_version(Size) when Size > 10 -> 
    do_larger();
when_version(Size) when Size < 10 -> 
    do_smaller().
```

See [Guard Sequences](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id75235) and [Function Declaration Syntax](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions.html#id70188) in the reference.

For a tutorial read [Guards, Guards!](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards) in [Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/) which is a great online Erlang tutorial BTW.

Comment: Guards can also be used in case and receive statements.

Comment: Either use when as a guard or use case .. of in a function.